# TinyMCE Moxie Player Media Splash Image?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, flash

Is there a way to get moxie player, which is packaged with TinyMCE, to display a splash image when you embed a video via the WYSIWYG tool?  I've been Googling and playing with it for a while with no success at this point.  I'm using TinyMCE 3.4.2 in production and have tried 3.4.3 in development, but it doesn't seem to work correctly.  Honestly, I'm not even sure what the actual params are for this player since the documentation on the legal flashvars appears to be non existent. From what I can tell, the "poster" param should be what I need, but setting that when I embed the video object seems to do nothing. The only official documentation I've found so far is: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Plugin:media and that just gives the general params to pass into TinyMCE for the media plugin itself, not how to actually use the player.

Here is what I'm currently setting in the flashvars param tag

```
<param name="flashvars" value="url=http%3A//url/to/some.flv&amp;poster=http%3A//url/to/some.jpg" />
```

Any ideas? I'd prefer to keep using the stock TinyMCE implementation if at all possible and this player, along with the WYSIWYG tool otherwise addresses the business issue perfectly for my company.

Comment: Try to replace `&amp;` by `?` in the url.

Comment: I just dropped them a note to ask where the Flex code is for [that SWF](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/tree/master/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/media). I'm pretty sure omitting source code for that binary file constitutes an LGPL violation; hopefully they'll realize that and post it soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it with current version of moxieplayer.

swfdump (from Flex SDK) on moxiplayer.swf doesn't show any reference to the poster parameter, just the url one.

This is an [open request feature](http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_view.php?id=4935). Just vote for it!

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can only set a poster image using the HTML5 Video tag. You can validate this [here](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php) by clicking the insert media button, selecting HTML5 video and assigning a poster image in the advanced tab.

After that just hit submit to see the resulting example and the corresponding HTML.